# Oracle odbc driver not registered IIS

Tags: c#, oracle, iis-7, provider

I know this as been asked many times. I'm really struggling on this. I have a 32bit app on IIS7, I have the Oracle client installed which is 32bit. I have the PATH set for Oracle home folder. I can see that the 32bit dirvers are installed in the wow64 (odbc data sources.exe) folder. I can see the IIS app is running in 32bit mode. Everything is there.

I have a test console app that can connect to Oracle but the II7 app just keeps ticking, provider not registered.. Both have the same code the same connection string.

I have enable the app pool to run 32bit apps. I have run the command `aspreg_iis -enable -i`

I have un-installed and reinstalled the Oracle client tools..

Nothing wants to work..

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all versions of ODP seem to work equally. V 12b seems to work best for 32bit apps on 64bit PCs. I'd remove other versions, install that and make sure that only files for that version are in the GAC and in the path variable.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply. I have managed to sort out the issue by restarting the machine. I know.... ;)